# How to confirm if a transaction is confirmed for a wallet app？

Tags: transactions

Our wallet client wants to check if a transaction issued by some an account is confirmed or not. I know history_api_plugin provides API for query actions related to the account. But if the filter for that plugin is *, there would be a lot of information saved to the memory mapped file which might break nodeos. Is there any solution to handle this common requirement? or do I need to implement a plugin to handle such requests?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the the transaction ID, you can query a `nodeos` instance to check in which block the transaction was included, if any, and if the block is before or after the latest irreversible block.

```
$ cleos get transaction <trx_id>
```

should return the block if it was submitted in any block.

If you don't have the transaction ID, and you want to store transcation, without storing everything (`*`), the filter flag allows you to specify conditions:

```
Config Options for eosio::history_plugin:                                                          
  -f [ --filter-on ] arg                Track actions which match                                  
                                        receiver:action:actor. Actor may be                        
                                        blank to include all. Action and Actor                     
                                        both blank allows all from Recieiver.                      
                                        Receiver may not be blank.                                 
  -f [ --filter-out ] arg               Do not track actions which match       
                                        receiver:action:actor. Action and Actor
                                        both blank excludes all from Reciever. 
                                        Actor blank excludes all from                              
                                        reciever:action. Receiver may not be  
                                        blank.
```

Similar options exist if you use `mongo_db_plugin`:

```
  --mongodb-filter-on arg               Mongodb: Track actions which match     
                                        receiver:action:actor. Actor may be   
                                        blank to include all. Receiver and    
                                        Action may not be blank. Default is * 
                                        include everything.                    
  --mongodb-filter-out arg              Mongodb: Do not track actions which 
                                        match receiver:action:actor. Action and
                                        Actor both blank excludes all from     
                                        reciever. Actor blank excludes all from
                                        reciever:action. Receiver may not be 
                                        blank.
```